# head output till a specific line

Tags: bash, unix, grep, unix-head

I have a bunch of files in the following format.

*A.txt*:

```
some text1      
more text2    
XXX
more text  
....  
XXX
.  
.  
XXX 
still more text  
text again
```

Each file has at least 3 lines that start with `XXX`. Now, for each file `A.txt` I want to write all the lines till the 3rd occurrence of `XXX` (in the above example it is till the line before `still more text`) to file `A_modified.txt`.

I want to do this in bash and came up with `grep -n -m 3 -w "^XXX$" * | cut -d: -f2` to get the corresponding line number in each file.

Is is possible to use `head` along with these line numbers to generate the required output?

PS: I know a simple python script would do the job but I am trying to do in this bash for no specific reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler method would be to use `awk`. Assuming there's nothing but files of interest in your present working directory, try:

```
for i in *; do awk '/^XXX$/ { c++ } c<=3' "$i" > "$i.modified"; done
```

Or if your files are very big:

```
for i in *; do awk '/^XXX$/ { c++ } c>=3 { exit }1' "$i" > "$i.modified"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

head -n will print out the first 'n' lines of the file

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in `ls *.txt`; do
  echo "searching $f" 

  line_number=`grep -n -m 3 -w "^XXX$" $f | cut -d: -f1 | tail -1` 

  # line_number now stores the line of the 3rd XXX 

  # now dump out the first 'line_number' of lines from this file
  head -n $line_number $f
done
```

Comment: Yeah...but the value of n is different for different files. My question is how to do this for all files in the directory.

Comment: Trivia?  He asked "is it possible to use head along with these line numbers".  How does my answer not apply?

Comment: @spartygw can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sure, @Graddy.  Your original question specifically stated 'head' and bash script so I've edited my original answer to show a bash script that does use head.  I'll leave error checking to you.